# TSQL: How to convert local time to UTC? (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, timezone, utc

We are dealing with an application that needs to handle global time data from different time zones and daylight savings time settings. The idea is to store everything in UTC format internally and only convert back and forth for the localized user interfaces. Does the SQL Server offer any mechanisms for dealing with the translations given a time, a country and a timezone?

This must be a common problem, so I'm surprised google wouldn't turn up anything usable.

Any pointers?

Comment: I have my mssql-server linked to a mysql-server. I wonder if it is possible to run mysql CONVERT_TZ(time,srczone,dstzone) on the queries :-)
Strange this function is missing; it is built into linux.

Comment: @BuschnicK See my answer below. Actually I think you can accept it even so it's easier for others to find.

Comment: The short answer: there is no built-in way to do this before SQL Server 2016, so it will require custom code on earlier versions.

Comment: The medium answer: all time offset functionality before SQL Server 2016 only worked with absolute offsets, with no support for the variable offsets that occur in most time zones due to Daylight Saving Time.  Queries do not have any way of accessing time offsets except for whatever happens to be the current offset of the server's local time, which is useless for trying to automate conversion.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

7 years passed and...
actually there's this new SQL Server 2016 feature that does exactly what you need.
It is called AT TIME ZONE and it converts date to a specified time zone considering DST (daylight saving time) changes.
More info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx

Comment: No longer working on this - not at that project, not at SQL Server, not at the same company and not even in the same country ;-) So it won't help me, but I'll upvote it for people finding this question now.

Comment: @BuschnicK yeah, I figure, but I got here looking for a solution to the same problem you had so I decided to post an aswer now that there is a real solution :D

Comment: The question is for SQL Server 2008. Please update the question if you accept this answer. Thx

Comment: How do you use this to convert to UTC, which is not a time zone?

Comment: To convert to UTC you can do 'AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'.

Comment: @Piotr Owsiak: Yea, but it assumes that the input time is UTC, which is pointless if you want to convert from local time to UTC... So 7 years passed, and they still don't think it's worth handling this properly...

Answer (score 76):

This works for dates that currently have the same UTC offset as SQL Server's host; it doesn't account for daylight savings changes. Replace `YOUR_DATE` with the local date to convert.

`SELECT DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), YOUR_DATE);`

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea but it only works for exactly one timezone - the local machine's. We need it to work for arbitrary timezones though...

Comment: clever but yeah, watch out for timezones.

Comment: This doesn't account for daylight savings time

Comment: No! The difference is dependent on the exact date. It depends on daylight-savings.

Comment: In my case I just needed the 1 timezone, and this worked great! Thanks.

Comment: I also only use one timezone and the times I'm converting are all today so I don't need to worry about DST issues, but I found I had to use select dateadd(second, (-1 * datediff(second, getutcdate(), getdate())), YOUR_DATE), otherwise I was 2 * my difference off.

Comment: This works well if you know your running today not historically, thanks

Comment: The question was about multiple time zones. This only talks about a single one - whichever TZ the server is in.

Answer (score 22):

While a few of these answers will get you in the ballpark, you cannot do what you're trying to do with arbitrary dates for SqlServer 2005 and earlier because of daylight savings time. Using the difference between the current local and current UTC will give me the offset as it exists today. I have not found a way to determine what the offset would have been for the date in question.

That said, I know that SqlServer 2008 provides some new date functions that may address that issue, but folks using an earlier version need to be aware of the limitations.

Our approach is to persist UTC and perform the conversion on the client side where we have more control over the conversion's accuracy.

Answer (score 22):

Here is the code to convert one zone `DateTime` to another zone `DateTime`

```
DECLARE @UTCDateTime DATETIME = GETUTCDATE();
DECLARE @ConvertedZoneDateTime DATETIME;

-- 'UTC' to 'India Standard Time' DATETIME
SET @ConvertedZoneDateTime = @UTCDateTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time'
SELECT @UTCDateTime AS UTCDATE,@ConvertedZoneDateTime AS IndiaStandardTime

-- 'India Standard Time' to 'UTC' DATETIME
SET @UTCDateTime = @ConvertedZoneDateTime AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
SELECT @ConvertedZoneDateTime AS IndiaStandardTime,@UTCDateTime AS UTCDATE
```

*Note*: `AT TIME ZONE` **works only on SQL Server 2016+** and the advantage is that it *automatically considers Daylight* when converting to a particular Time zone

Comment: I love this, if for no other reason than the fact that it shows you can chain multiple `AT TIME ZONE` calls (phrases?) together!  Simply elegant.  I said earlier that https://stackoverflow.com/a/44579178/112764 met my needs, but this is even better.  Major kudos.

Comment: `DECLARE @UTCDateTime DATETIME = GETUTCDATE();`  

`DECLARE @ConvertedZoneDateTime DATETIME;`  


`-- 'UTC' to 'India Standard Time' to 'Eastern Standard Time' DATETIME`
`SET @ConvertedZoneDateTime = @UTCDateTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'`  

`SELECT @UTCDateTime AS UTCDATE,@ConvertedZoneDateTime AS EasternStandardTime`  

Yes, you can chain multiple  `AT TIME ZONE` calls, but **From** and **To** is enough for any conversion and most we needed

Answer (score 17):

For SQL Server 2016 and newer, and Azure SQL Database, use the built in [`AT TIME ZONE` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql).

For older editions of SQL Server, you can use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project to convert between IANA standard time zones, [as listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

UTC to Local is like this:

```
SELECT Tzdb.UtcToLocal('2015-07-01 00:00:00', 'America/Los_Angeles')
```

Local to UTC is like this:

```
SELECT Tzdb.LocalToUtc('2015-07-01 00:00:00', 'America/Los_Angeles', 1, 1)
```

The numeric options are flag for controlling the behavior when the local time values are affected by daylight saving time.  These are described in detail in the project's documentation.

Comment: How man... this project of Matt is great and does not require the CLR. Matt deserves much credit for this +100

Answer (score 14):

SQL Server 2008 has a type called `datetimeoffset`. It's really useful for this type of stuff.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx

Then you can use the function `SWITCHOFFSET` to move it from one timezone to another, but still keeping the same UTC value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx

Rob

Comment: SWITCHOFFSET doesn't account for daylight savings, so it is only useful in some situations.

Comment: No. But the question was about being able to handle switching to whichever time zone was requested.

Comment: From the question "different time zones and daylight savings time settings". We too are looking for a solution for local times. Your suggestion doesn't solve the daylight savings issue does it?

Comment: Any time when you need to detect the time zone at a client and then have the database return times in the specified time zone, the SWITCHOFFSET function is very useful.

Comment: @RobFarley Detecting the time zone at the client and using SWITCHOFFSET can still get things wrong. You need to know whether or not the date and time you are converting has Daylight Savings Time applied or not. Simply detecting the time zone and applying the current offset to UTC can be an hour off -- and that's in a simple case where all your conversions are in the same country. Not every country switches to/from daylight savings time on the same dates. SWITCHOFFSET does work nicely if you store local time and know the difference between the original and target zone within the same country.

Comment: Yes. If you know you want to switch from GMT-5 to GMT+930, then you can do that, keeping the order of times unchanged. But you need to know that you're interested in 0930 and not 1030.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to lean towards using DateTimeOffset for all date-time storage that isn't related to a local event (ie: meeting/party, etc, 12pm-3pm at the museum).

To get the current DTO as UTC:

```
DECLARE @utcNow DATETIMEOFFSET = CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, SYSUTCDATETIME())
DECLARE @utcToday DATE = CONVERT(DATE, @utcNow);
DECLARE @utcTomorrow DATE = DATEADD(D, 1, @utcNow);
SELECT  @utcToday [today]
        ,@utcTomorrow [tomorrow]
        ,@utcNow [utcNow]
```

NOTE: I will always use UTC when sending over the wire... client-side JS can easily get to/from local UTC. See: `new Date().toJSON()` ...

The following JS will handle parsing a UTC/GMT date in ISO8601 format to a local datetime.

```
if (typeof Date.fromISOString != 'function') {
  //method to handle conversion from an ISO-8601 style string to a Date object
  //  Date.fromISOString("2009-07-03T16:09:45Z")
  //    Fri Jul 03 2009 09:09:45 GMT-0700
  Date.fromISOString = function(input) {
    var date = new Date(input); //EcmaScript5 includes ISO-8601 style parsing
    if (!isNaN(date)) return date;

    //early shorting of invalid input
    if (typeof input !== "string" || input.length < 10 || input.length > 40) return null;

    var iso8601Format = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})((([T ](\d{2}):(\d{2})(:(\d{2})(\.(\d{1,12}))?)?)?)?)?([Zz]|([-+])(\d{2})\:?(\d{2}))?$/;

    //normalize input
    var input = input.toString().replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');

    if (!iso8601Format.test(input))
      return null; //invalid format

    var d = input.match(iso8601Format);
    var offset = 0;

    date = new Date(+d[1], +d[2]-1, +d[3], +d[7] || 0, +d[8] || 0, +d[10] || 0, Math.round(+("0." + (d[12] || 0)) * 1000));

    //use specified offset
    if (d[13] == 'Z') offset = 0-date.getTimezoneOffset();
    else if (d[13]) offset = ((parseInt(d[15],10) * 60) + (parseInt(d[16],10)) * ((d[14] == '-') ? 1 : -1)) - date.getTimezoneOffset();

    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (offset * 60000));

    if (date.getTime() <= new Date(-62135571600000).getTime()) // CLR DateTime.MinValue
      return null;

    return date;
  };
}
```

Comment: +1 I've too switched to DateTimeOffset. It avoids a number of issues with UTC + local conversions. However, for similar reasons, I recommend sending values with an offset over-the-wire (via JSON) as well.

Comment: As a note, I do what you do *exactly* the other way around. For DateTimes that are tied to a local event, I store a DateTimeOffset. For a DateTime that is not tied to a local event, I store a DateTime in UTC. The former has two relevant datapoints (when is it in local time, and what local time is that), the latter only one (when is it)

Comment: @Martijn But the timezone doesn't give you the location, and you have to stored separately anyhow.

Comment: @tracker1 That only works when the location has a way of knowing its timezone, and even then it's a complete pain to convert.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, to some degree as detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/03/18/using-time-zone-data-in-sql-server-2008.aspx). 
The approach I've used (pre-2008) is to do the conversion in the .NET business logic before inserting into the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GETUTCDATE() function to get UTC datetime
Probably you can select difference between GETUTCDATE() and GETDATE() and use this difference to ajust your dates to UTC

But I agree with previous message, that it is much easier to control right datetime in the business layer (in .NET, for example).

Comment: No! The difference is dependent on the exact date. It depends on daylight-savings.

Comment: Does not account for daylight savings. I was using solutions like this for some time and it caused major issues. You have to determine if the date you are comparing against is in DST.

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(34), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()), 29, 5)`

Returns (for example):

`-06:0`

Not 100% positive this will always work.

Answer (score -1):

Sample usage:

```
SELECT
    Getdate=GETDATE()
    ,SysDateTimeOffset=SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
    ,SWITCHOFFSET=SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),0)
    ,GetutcDate=GETUTCDATE()
GO
```

Returns:

```
Getdate SysDateTimeOffset   SWITCHOFFSET    GetutcDate
2013-12-06 15:54:55.373 2013-12-06 15:54:55.3765498 -08:00  2013-12-06 23:54:55.3765498 +00:00  2013-12-06 23:54:55.373
```