# SQL Server 2008 - How to convert GMT(UTC) datetime to local datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have an insert proc that passes in `GETDATE()` as one of the values because each insert also stores when it was inserted. This is hosted on SQL Azure - which uses GMT.

Now, when I am receiving messages, I have the GMT date stored for each of them in their timestamp columns, how do I convert this to the local `datetime` for wherever you are when you are accessing my page?

Thanks.

Comment: Did the server time change? Can you check?

Comment: Umm, it's running on SQL Azure. How would I check?

Comment: can't you simply do a "SELECT GETDATE() GO" and see if that matches what you're expecting?

Comment: You can't Azure should be running of GMT. Are you getting that or a local time?

Comment: @Mat - for some reason when I execute simple queries in Azure it doesn't work right =/

Comment: @Dustin - I don't know what I'm getting, lol.

Comment: @Slandau, when you say "when I execute simple queries in Azure it doesn't work right" what do you mean by "doesn't work right"?

Comment: The result of that query Dustin?

Comment: What is the time difference between what is being returned by getdate() and what you're expecting?  What timezone are you in?  Also, what does sysdatetimeoffset() return?

Comment: SELECT GETDATE() GO - returns 5/19 but 8:54pm

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns the same thing

Comment: sysdatetimeoffset() also the same thing

Comment: That's GMT time. You'll have to convert it to your local timezone (but keep in mind this will be incorrect for people in OTHER time zones)

Comment: @Mike M. how do I make it work for everyone in their local timezone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL: How to convert local time to UTC? (SQL Server 2008)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205142/tsql-how-to-convert-local-time-to-utc-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
declare @InputUtcDateTime datetime2 = '2011-05-20 06:30:18'

declare @LocalDateTime datetime2 = dateadd(minute, datepart(TZoffset, sysdatetimeoffset()), @InputUtcDateTime)
print @LocalDateTime
```

or

```
declare @InputUtcDateTime datetime2 = '2011-05-20 06:30:18'

declare @LocalDateTime datetime2 = dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, sysutcdatetime(), sysdatetime()), @InputUtcDateTime)
print @LocalDateTime
```

Comment: Both of these are incorrect. They rely on the assumption that the offset for the local timezone of today is the same as the offset for the local timezone at the time referred to by the input UTC date.

Since the local timezone might be subject to DST, it's offset might be different in the past than it is today.

Comment: @wasabi +1 - you are correct about the limitation of this approach.  However I disagree that it is incorrect. It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Trying to get the correct time back for a local timezone, given an arbitrary input time?

Comment: To handle DST conversions you will need a lookup table like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14769/SQL-Server-Convert-UTC-to-Local-Time

Comment: As @wasabi explains, this approach won't work. It assumes that the server's local time always had the same offset from GMT/UTC - even for Greenwich, this is not true, due to daylight savings!

Comment: without knowing client timezone how could we convert utc datetime to client local date time ?

Comment: I do not think this should be listed as the accepted answer when it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the Daylight Savings issue, why not simplify with:

```
yourDateTime - getutcdate() + getdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

For MST as an example... considering each DTM is stored in GMT already, that simplifies things..

```
SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, [ColumnName]), '-07:00')
```

Now, if your local date/time is something other than GMT/UTC, you'll likely want to use the following...

```
SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET([ColumnName], datepart(tz,sysdatetimeoffset())),'+00:00')
```

Here's the breakdown.

- `SWITCHOFFSET` - converts a DateTimeOffset value to a different timezone, while preserving the offset.
- `TODATETIMEOFFSET` - converts a DateTime value to a DateTimeOffset value at a specified timezone.
- `DATEPART` - in this case is getting the timezone part of the local datetime.
- `'+00:00'` - the target offset, in the second example is UTC/GMT target, from local... the former example is to MST.

NOTE/WARNING: I don't believe that this accounts for Daylight Savings Time, which could be an issue for you.  If absolute preservation isn't necessary, you may want to simply add a secondary column, with the rough conversion and go forward safely.

You may want to abstract the logic into a function call, in order to account for the preservation of DST... it shouldn't be excessively difficult to do, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DateTime_GMTFromLocal](@LocalTime DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME2(3)
AS
BEGIN
/*
=============================================
 Author:        Mark Griffiths
 Create date:   29/05/2018
 Description:   BST runs from 02:00AM on the last Sunday of March to the same time on the last Sunday of October.       
    The Series of DATEDIFFs and DATEADDS below function as follows
    1   ●   Count the number of months there have been between the given date and start of computer time
    2   ●   Add that number of months to the end of the first month to get the end of the given month
    3   ●   Count the number of days there have been between the end of the given month and the first Saturday
    4   ●   Add that number of days to the calculated end of the given month
    5   ●   Add Two hours to that time as the clocks go back at 02:00 in the morning

    I know that the tabbing below makes it all look odd, but the description above is the best way I could find to comment things, given the nesting...
    The comments in the code below should help find the nesting levels and the numbers refer to the bullet points above.
=============================================
-- Test Variables --
DECLARE @GMTime DATETIME2(3) = '2018-05-01 12:00:00.000'
*/

    DECLARE @RealTime As DATETIME2(3)
    DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(4)
    SET @Year = CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(YEAR,@GMTime))
    DECLARE @StartOfBST AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @EndOfBST AS DATETIME
    SELECT
        @StartOfBST =
        DATEADD     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            (                                                       --                                      |
             HOUR                                                   --                                      |
            ,2                                                      --                                      |
            ,DATEADD    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------       |
                (                                                   --                              |       |
                 DAY                                                --                              |       |
                ,DATEDIFF       -------------------------------------------------------------       |       |
                    (                                               --                      |       |       |
                     DAY                                            --                      |       |       |
                    ,'19000107'                                     --                      |       |       5
                    ,DATEADD            ---------------------------------------------       |       |       |
                        (                                           --              |       3       4       |
                         MONTH                                      --              |       |       |       |
                        ,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CONVERT(DATE,'03/01/' + @Year)) -- 1      2       |       |       |
                        ,CONVERT(DATE,'01/31/1900')                 --              |       |       |       |
                        )               ---------------------------------------------       |       |       |
                    )/7*7       -------------------------------------------------------------       |       |
                    ,'19000107'                                     --                              |       |
                )               ---------------------------------------------------------------------       |
            ),      -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @EndOfBST =
        DATEADD(HOUR,2,DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'19000107',DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CONVERT(DATE,'10/01/' + @Year)),30))/7*7,'19000107'))
    SET @RealTime = CASE
                    WHEN @GMTime BETWEEN @StartOfBST AND @EndOfBST THEN DATEADD(HOUR,-1,@GMTime)
                    ELSE @GMTime
                END
RETURN @RealTime;
--SELECT @RealTime
END
```

*EDIT: Changed `CONVERT(DATE,'01/30/1900')` to `CONVERT(DATE,'01/31/1900')` as since 45BC, January has had 31 days. This caused some times an incorrect result for 2019, and any others where the last Sunday in March is the 31st.

Comment: this works perfectly although i had to change the -1 to +1 at the end to change utc time to GMT

Comment: yeah, you can go either way like that - I made two functions, one for each way and reference them separately in my scripts - they differ only by the `+-1`. PS. It amazes me that the accepted answer (which is upvoted) does not work!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function which works on historic data. I wrote it for British Summer time - which unfortunately occurs on the last Sunday of the months of March and October, making the logic a little convoluted.

Basically the hard coded date part 01/03 is looking for the last Sunday in March and 01/10 is looking for the last Sunday in October (which is when the clocks go forward and back here). NOTE: IF YOUR SERVER IS USING NATIVE US DATES REVERSE THESE TWO DATE PARTS TO 03/01 and 10/01!!!!

So you feed it a UTC date and it'll automatically work out whether an historic date is BST or GMT. Not the best thing to use on a big data set but it's a solution.

Run this script to create the function and call it inline in your select. SQL 2008 has a problem with user defined functions, it seems, it puts a redline under the code, but it still runs it as long as you use the dbo prefix (SELECT dbo.UTCConvert(yourdate) to run it)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UTCConvert] 
(

    @p1 datetime
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result datetime


RETURN CASE 
WHEN
@p1 >
(DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'19000107',DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,'01/03/' + CAST(DATEPART(year,@p1) as CHAR)),30))/7*7,'19000107'))
AND
@p1<
(DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'19000107',DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,'01/10/' + CAST(DATEPART(year,@p1) as CHAR)),30))/7*7,'19000107'))
THEN (DATEADD(HH, 1, @p1)) 
ELSE @p1
END
END
```

Comment: If your server is using native US dates because it's located in the US, you've most likely got far more severe headaches. Odds are if you're looking at this question, you're storing dates from at least one location where daylight savings apply. That means at the very least you have to worry about the 2007 change in the shift dates. You may well have to worry about multiple timezones, possibly Arizona and maybe even the Navajo Nation. You really want to be storing either UTC or datetimeoffset in SQL Server and doing your date math in your business layer.