# How to convert GMT time to local time zone in sql

Tags: timezone

how can we convert the GMT to local SQL DATE?
When i store GMT time , then 1 hour is subtracted from this value.
please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 - How to convert GMT(UTC) datetime to local datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064674/sql-server-2008-how-to-convert-gmtutc-datetime-to-local-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous as written, but I am guessing that you want to convert a UTC datetime (sometimes called GMT or Zulu time) into a datetime in your local timezone.

You indicate that your local time zone is -1 hour offset from UTC time.

In this case you simply use the `DATEADD` function:

```
SET MyTimeLocal = DATEADD(HH, -1, MyTimeGMT)
```

Note that this will only work so long as your time zone really **is** one hour before UTC time. If your location uses daylight saving time, this will be wrong as soon as the time changes, and it will be *extra* wrong when the time to be converted falls in the crack of the clock change.

There are many better ways to do this in general, but to give a general solution we would need to know what version of SQL is being used and what exactly you are trying to accomplish.