# How to convert datetime to UTC in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, utc

Does any one know how can I convert datetime to UTC in sql?

Example:
If I have a datetime variable @test = '2014-09-09 9:00:00', how can I convert @test into UTC in SQL?

Comment: Is this a general sql question? Or is it for any specific RDMS (oracle,mysql,mssql)?

Comment: If MSSQL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460562/convert-datetime-to-utc-value-mssql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try below Query in SQL Server :

```
Declare @test as datetime
set @test = '2014-09-09 9:00:00'
SELECT DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), @test)
```

Comment: This does not take daylight savings into account.  See the many other SO posts about daylight savings and UTC.