# How to assume a DATETIME is in my local time zone, then convert to UTC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2016, I have a `date_time` column of type `DATETIME` that was inserted using the machine's local time zone. I need to convert this value to UTC.

I tried using

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19), date_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 127) + 'Z' AS Timestamp
```

but I realize now that it automatically assumes the `date_time` is already in UTC time so no conversion is made. I am not using `DATEADD` because it does not account for DST.

Is there a way I can tell SQL Server that the date time is in the machine's local time zone, then use AT TIME ZONE to convert it to UTC?

Edit: This is not a duplicate, since a comment in the approved answer ("Yea, but it assumes that the input time is UTC, which is pointless if you want to convert from local time to UTC") states the problem I have outlined in this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL: How to convert local time to UTC? (SQL Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205142/tsql-how-to-convert-local-time-to-utc-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I edited the original post. This is not a duplicate of that question, since a comment in the approved answer ("Yea, but it assumes that the input time is UTC, which is pointless if you want to convert from local time to UTC") states the problem I have outlined in this question.

Comment: There is no generic solution to this problem. Proof: If you are located within the EU and `date_time` contains `2019-10-27 02:30` "local time"---which occurs twice, due to clocks being reset at 03:00 to 02:00---, there are *two* possible matching UTC times.

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the data type of the captured date from `DATETIME` to `DATETIMEOFFSET`? It's going to be challenging, if not impossible, to retrofit a solution without knowing the base time zone of the legacy dates in the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AT TIME ZONE` is one half of the equation. The other is getting the machine's time zone, which even 2017 has no actual function or `SERVERPROPERTY` for -- you need to poke around in the registry. From SQL Server 2019 onwards (and Azure SQL), there's the [`CURRENT_TIMEZONE()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timezone-transact-sql), but (in a seemingly bizarre oversight) the return value of this cannot be used as the input to an `AT TIME ZONE` clause or correlated with `sys.time_zone_info`, so it's not clear what purpose that's supposed to serve.

```
DECLARE @TimeZone NVARCHAR(4000);
EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread 
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
    'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation', 
    'TimeZoneKeyName', 
    @TimeZone OUT;

-- For me, that's 'W. Europe Standard Time'

SELECT {ts '2019-03-31 02:00:00' } AT TIME ZONE @TimeZone AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
-- Yields '2019-03-31 01:00:00.000 +00:00', DST was not in effect

SELECT {ts '2019-03-31 03:00:00' } AT TIME ZONE @TimeZone AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
-- *Also* yields '2019-03-31 01:00:00.000 +00:00', DST was in effect
```

These examples illustrate the peril of having to convert time stamps that weren't recorded with actual offsets: in the "twilight zone" of DST turnover, you get times that are inherently ambiguous. The results of such adjustments are only mostly correct, skipping and duplicating an hour twice a year. Some data sets can live with that, some can't.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to tell the query what timezone the initial date is in, with an `AT TIME ZONE` clause after the initial value, and then the one you want to convert it to, with a second `AT TIME ZONE` clause after that.

The default return value is a `DATETIMEOFFSET`, so you'll have to `CAST/CONVERT` if you want  to drop the offset value. I'm in the US Central Time Zone, so I used that. You'll have to substitute the correct timezone for your server.

```
DECLARE @date_time DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT 
  @date_time AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_time_as_datetimeoffset;

SELECT 
  CAST(@date_time AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATETIME) AS utc_time_as_datetime;
```

Results:

```
+--------------------------------+
|   utc_time_as_datetimeoffset   |
+--------------------------------+
| 2019-04-25 13:29:01.057 +00:00 |
+--------------------------------+

+-------------------------+
|  utc_time_as_datetime   |
+-------------------------+
| 2019-04-25 13:29:01.057 |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer, but I can't assume what the initial timezone is, since the servers this will be used on can be different timezones.

Comment: Continuing in comments under the question, in case I end up deleting this answer since it doesn't seem to suit your needs.

Comment: This explanation combined with the above answer helped me get and understand a solution. Thank you.